# Dataframe filtering algorithm scales badly in memory and performance

Tags: python, pandas

The user has a number of dropdowns they can use to filter their data. Currently there are 4 dropdowns, but I would like 8. The dataframe sizes to filter can be quite large, well into the thousands of rows, with 10-20 columns.

Because the amount of options on each filter dropdown is overwhelming, I filter the options available on each dropdown based on the user's selections in the other dropdowns. Effectively, each dropdown has had the dataframe filtered by all of the other dropdowns (except itself).

This is great for the users, but does not appear to scale well from the servers perspective. It appears to have a near factorial effect on each filter I add.

One idea was to apply each filter in isolation, and then do the unions of each result, however this would still need a factorial number of operations per filter. Am I missing any other way?

```
import pandas as pd
import random

data = {
'Customer': ['David', 'Alice', 'Isaac', 'Hannah', 'Hannah', 'Emily', 'David', 'Rachel', 'Charlie', 'Samuel','Nathan', 'Bob', 'Alice', 'Charlie', 'Grace', 'Hannah', 'Quinn', 'Taylor', 'Alice', 'Rachel'],'Supplier': ['Supplier B', 'Supplier E', 'Supplier D', 'Supplier B', 'Supplier D', 'Supplier E', 'Supplier C','Supplier A', 'Supplier B', 'Supplier D', 'Supplier C', 'Supplier C', 'Supplier B', 'Supplier B','Supplier C', 'Supplier A', 'Supplier A', 'Supplier D', 'Supplier A', 'Supplier C'],'Product': ['Product 3', 'Product 5', 'Product 3', 'Product 1', 'Product 4', 'Product 5','Product 1','Product 4', 'Product 1', 'Product 5', 'Product 3', 'Product 5', 'Product 3','Product 5','Product 2', 'Product 1', 'Product 1', 'Product 2', 'Product 3', 'Product 1'],'SalesAmount': [975, 338, 987, 203, 489, 384, 564, 750, 954, 473, 266, 479, 463, 314, 786, 373, 818, 799, 763, 173]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


def filter_df(df, dropdown_selection, column_name):
    if dropdown_selection == ["All"]:
        return df

    df = df.loc[df[column_name].isin(dropdown_selection)]
    return df


def get_dropdown_data(df, column_name):
    column_as_list = df[column_name].dropna().to_list()
    dropdown_list = pd.unique(column_as_list)
    return dropdown_list


df = df.drop_duplicates()

# Dropdown selections
supplier_dropdown = ["Supplier B"]
product_dropdown = ["All"]
customer_dropdown = ["All"]

df_supplier_filter = filter_df(df, supplier_dropdown, "Supplier")
df_product_filter = filter_df(df, product_dropdown, "Product")
df_customer_filter = filter_df(df, customer_dropdown, "Customer")

# this is the part that I'm not sure how to do in a scalable way with many dropdowns
df_product_supplier_filter = filter_df(df_product_filter, supplier_dropdown, "Supplier")
df_customer_product_filter = filter_df(df_customer_filter, product_dropdown, "Product")
df_supplier_customer_filter = filter_df(
    df_supplier_filter, customer_dropdown, "Customer"
)

# Output dropdown options now available
new_customer_dropdown_options = get_dropdown_data(
    df_product_supplier_filter, "Customer"
)
new_supplier_dropdown_options = get_dropdown_data(
    df_customer_product_filter, "Supplier"
)
new_product_dropdown_options = get_dropdown_data(df_supplier_customer_filter, "Product")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid chaining the selections as this create an intermediate DataFrame at each step.

Instead build a single boolean mask. For that use a dictionary of your `{'column_name': ['selector']}` with a special case for `['All']` and [`numpy.logical_and.reduce`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html):

```
import numpy

def filter_df(df, selections):
    m = np.logical_and.reduce([(df[col].isin(sel) | (sel == ['All']))
                               for col, sel in selections.items()])
    return df[m]

selections = {'Supplier': ['Supplier B'],
              'Product': ['All'],
              'Customer': ['All']
              }

out = filter_df(df, selections)

print(out)
```

Output:

```
   Customer    Supplier    Product  SalesAmount
0     David  Supplier B  Product 3          975
3    Hannah  Supplier B  Product 1          203
8   Charlie  Supplier B  Product 1          954
12    Alice  Supplier B  Product 3          463
13  Charlie  Supplier B  Product 5          314
```

Other example:

```
selections = {'Supplier': ['Supplier B'],
              'Product': ['All'],
              'Customer': ['Alice', 'Charlie']
              }

filter_df(df, selections)

   Customer    Supplier    Product  SalesAmount
8   Charlie  Supplier B  Product 1          954
12    Alice  Supplier B  Product 3          463
13  Charlie  Supplier B  Product 5          314
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**:

If you need to create more complicated conditional filtering, I suggest assembling your own query strings and using pandas query(). This would be a good approach if the number of conditions you want to apply varies or the structure of your logic changes under different circumstances.

```
data = {
'Customer': ['David', 'Alice', 'Isaac', 'Hannah', 'Hannah', 'Emily', 'David', 'Rachel', 'Charlie', 'Samuel','Nathan', 'Bob', 'Alice', 'Charlie', 'Grace', 'Hannah', 'Quinn', 'Taylor', 'Alice', 'Rachel'],'Supplier': ['Supplier B', 'Supplier E', 'Supplier D', 'Supplier B', 'Supplier D', 'Supplier E', 'Supplier C','Supplier A', 'Supplier B', 'Supplier D', 'Supplier C', 'Supplier C', 'Supplier B', 'Supplier B','Supplier C', 'Supplier A', 'Supplier A', 'Supplier D', 'Supplier A', 'Supplier C'],'Product': ['Product 3', 'Product 5', 'Product 3', 'Product 1', 'Product 4', 'Product 5','Product 1','Product 4', 'Product 1', 'Product 5', 'Product 3', 'Product 5', 'Product 3','Product 5','Product 2', 'Product 1', 'Product 1', 'Product 2', 'Product 3', 'Product 1'],'SalesAmount': [975, 338, 987, 203, 489, 384, 564, 750, 954, 473, 266, 479, 463, 314, 786, 373, 818, 799, 763, 173]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Dropdown selections
filt_options = {"Supplier" : ["Supplier B"],
                "Product" : ["All"],
                "Customer" : ["All"]
                }

query_list = []

for option, mask in filt_options.items():

    """ You can build alot of conditional logic inside here. """

    if "All" not in mask:
        valid_list = filt_options.get(option)
        query_list.append(f"{option} in {valid_list}")
        
query_str = " & ".join(query_list)

df_filtered = df.query(query_str)
```

Output:

```
Supplier in ['Supplier B']
   Customer    Supplier    Product  SalesAmount
0     David  Supplier B  Product 3          975
3    Hannah  Supplier B  Product 1          203
8   Charlie  Supplier B  Product 1          954
12    Alice  Supplier B  Product 3          463
13  Charlie  Supplier B  Product 5          314
```

A little more complicated

```
# Dropdown selections
filt_options = {"Supplier" : ["Supplier B"],
                "Product" : ["Product 3"],
                "Customer" : ["All"]
                }

Supplier in ['Supplier B'] & Product in ['Product 3']
   Customer    Supplier    Product  SalesAmount
0     David  Supplier B  Product 3          975
12    Alice  Supplier B  Product 3          463
```

Comment: Hi jesse, thanks for the response! I was able to get working with adding an else block for the "All" case. However, the mask method presented by moz seems to perform even faster when multiple masks are used. This was still quite good though!

Times for .query():
Elapsed time: 0.0059 seconds
Elapsed time: 0.0095 seconds
Elapsed time: 0.0116 seconds

Times for mask:
Elapsed time: 0.0051 seconds
Elapsed time: 0.0056 seconds
Elapsed time: 0.0043 seconds

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:

Use a single mask.

```
import pandas as pd
import random

data = {
'Customer': ['David', 'Alice', 'Isaac', 'Hannah', 'Hannah', 'Emily', 'David', 'Rachel', 'Charlie', 'Samuel','Nathan', 'Bob', 'Alice', 'Charlie', 'Grace', 'Hannah', 'Quinn', 'Taylor', 'Alice', 'Rachel'],'Supplier': ['Supplier B', 'Supplier E', 'Supplier D', 'Supplier B', 'Supplier D', 'Supplier E', 'Supplier C','Supplier A', 'Supplier B', 'Supplier D', 'Supplier C', 'Supplier C', 'Supplier B', 'Supplier B','Supplier C', 'Supplier A', 'Supplier A', 'Supplier D', 'Supplier A', 'Supplier C'],'Product': ['Product 3', 'Product 5', 'Product 3', 'Product 1', 'Product 4', 'Product 5','Product 1','Product 4', 'Product 1', 'Product 5', 'Product 3', 'Product 5', 'Product 3','Product 5','Product 2', 'Product 1', 'Product 1', 'Product 2', 'Product 3', 'Product 1'],'SalesAmount': [975, 338, 987, 203, 489, 384, 564, 750, 954, 473, 266, 479, 463, 314, 786, 373, 818, 799, 763, 173]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Dropdown selections
supplier_dropdown = ["Supplier B"]
product_dropdown = ["All"]
customer_dropdown = ["All"]

mask = (df['Supplier'].isin(supplier_dropdown)) & (df['Product'].isin(product_dropdown)) & (df['Customer'].isin(customer_dropdown))

df_filtered = df[mask].copy()
```

Comment: This should improve performance. If memory is an issue then you can apply this on batches of the dataset, one at a time.

Comment: Although the idea of a single mask is correct, the way you did it won't work. You didn't create a boolean Series.

Comment: My mistake,  you're right. I updated the code to reflect boolean masks being applied.

Comment: It's still incorrect (this time the logic, not syntax), you should always run your code and provide the expected output to ensure not having an error.

Comment: If you are planning on doing more complicated things like using 'All' as a filter,  then I would suggest using a pandas query instead. It depends on what you're plan is.

Comment: That's what is interesting, I provided an approach